# Why does ERC add ` to my nickname

Tags: erc

Weirdly when I try to log onto freenode using ERC, a ` is added to my nickname, which results in the name not being found on the server. I get the following output in the *Messages* buffer - I have replaced my real nick with nickname.

```
Connecting to irc.freenode.net:6667... ...done
Logging in as 'nickname'...
Logging in as 'nickname`'... done
```

Using ERC 5.3 on Emacs 24.3.5.1 on OS X

Answer (score 13):

I get this behavior when I, or somebody else, is already logged into the server with my original username. If I open ERC twice, logging in as `tikhon` both times, the second login is automatically changed to `` tikhon` ``.

This can happen if you first connect and then time out. The IRC server gives you a grace period before kicking you off; if you try to log in while the old you is still on the server, your name will get a `` ` `` appended.

With a mathematical bent, you can read it as "tikhon prime" :).

You can change this character by customizing `erc-nick-uniquifier`, e.g.

```
(setq erc-nick-uniquifier "_")
```

to use `nickname_` instead of `` nickname` ``

Comment: Thanks, this gave me an opportunity to use /MSG NickServ RELEASE to claim my nick back :-)

Comment: @mac: Oh, I never realized you could do that on IRC. Neat.

Comment: Also, If you need to use another nick instead of adding a uniquifier character at the end, you can add your preferred nick to the list `erc-nick` with a simple `(add-to-list 'erc-nick "ircnick")`